# Three voltage levels driver

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, mosfet-driver, ccd

I am trying to come up with a circuit that would have two 3.3 V logic inputs and that outputs three different voltages 15 V, 0V, -7 V (Vhigh, Vmid, Vlow) into the same line (CCD vertical driver) that drives a moderate load. Target frequency is up to 1MHz.

As a source of inspiration I am looking at [this circuit](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/collateral/kai-68pin-head-bd-a-gevb_schematic.pdf):

[image: example]

V1T_3rd_AFE and V1T_AFE swing between Vhigh-Vmid and Vmid-Vlow respectively and come from an Analog Front End that I do not wish to use in my project.

Currently I've come up with the following circuit that simulates the desired result and uses a [ISL55110](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/analog-products/amplifiers/powerfetccd-drivers/isl55110-dual-high-speed-mosfet-driver) driver to transform the 3.3 V signal to 12 V and an [LT1365](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt1365.html) op-amp to invert one of the outputs to Vmid-Vlow level:

[image]

However, I feel like it's overkill to use such a well specced op-amp for a simple voltage inversion.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to simplify my current setup? Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Why not to use 2 opamps instead? The ISLxxx is a MOSFET gate driver, so not very appropriate for high speed level converter, it's for power driving you won't never reach 1MHz without issues.

Comment: If I understand correctly two IRF7309 would require three op amps to operate: Vhigh-Vmid section can be done with one noninverting part, Vmid-Vlow section would require buffer op amp + inverting part.

Comment: ISL55110 is rated for ~10ns propagation delay and ~2ns rise and fall time. Could you please clarify why it won't work?

Comment: @IvanDemyachenko What kind of drain-source drop in C15 do you expect when supplying 0V and C15 in the top diagram is on? I'm assuming not much but the body diode is staring at me, too.

Comment: @jonk to be honest, I do not completely understand the question - if the simulation is anything to go by if IN_A is low and IN_B oscillates between hign and low - drain output from top section oscillates between 15v and ~10v.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, it seems possible to use buffer circuit like 74HC4050 (or similar) connected to with GND=-7V and VCC=0V to drive the lower MOSFET part but it would require a clamper circuit on its inputs to shift input down. AFAIK it also comes with a drawback that it has only one stable position.

Comment: Or maybe it would be appropriate to use an optoisolator to accomplish the voltage down shift.

Answer (score 0):

> Would anyone have any suggestions on how to simplify my current setup?

Use the ISL55111, it has an inverting pin on B then tie in-A and in-B to the PWM source, one will be inverted from the other.

The diagram for the ISL55111 should look like this (but they didn't show it graphically in the datasheet).

[image]
Source: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl55110-isl55111-datasheet

Comment: Still it would output 0 V or 12 V, but a lower part of the MOSFET circuit requires -7 V or 0 V